# If Table Name Exists, Change Table Name (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've created a macro that automatically takes a range of cells and formats them into a table.

I've set the default table name as "Table11", but because Table11 can only exist in the workbook once, I will experience an error if I try to use run the macro more than once.

Is there a way to modify my code to say something like "If table11 exists, then change the name to table12"?

I don't really care what the new table name is called, but I would like the code to be used as often as needed so that if table11 is already being used, name it table12. if table12 is already being used, use table13, etc...

Here is my code:

```
Sub formatMacro()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes).Name = "Table11"
Range("Table11[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
       With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table11").ShowTableStyleColumnStripes = True
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Selection.Rows.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to name the table.  Use `With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(...)` to work with the newly added table.

[image]

---

```
Sub CreateAndFormatTable()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, , xlYes)

        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
        With .Range
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = False
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        .ShowTableStyleColumnStripes = True
        .Range.Columns.AutoFit
        .Range.Rows.AutoFit
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```